# Pendulum hanging on a spinning Disk

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, physics, euler-lagrange-equation

It is a problem found in Physics. From the edge of a (in distance r to the center) disk a (mathematical) pendulum is hanging. The disk spins with a velocity w, which also stimulates the hanging pendulum.(As can be seen in the picture below)
[image]
[image]

The first intuition is to use Lagrange to solve the chaotic movement.
$
L=T-V
$
Our kinetic Energy would be:
$
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       T=\frac{1}{2} \cdot m (l^2 \cdot \dot{\phi}^2+l^2\cdot w^2\cdot sin^2(\phi))
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$

with the potential energy being:
$
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       V=-g \cdot m \cdot l \cdot cos(\phi))
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$

The Lagrangian would therefore be:
$
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       L=\frac{1}{2} \cdot m (l^2 \cdot \dot{\phi}^2+l^2\cdot w^2\cdot sin^2(\phi))+g \cdot m \cdot l \cdot cos(\phi))
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$

Now calculating the Euler-Lagrange  differential equation leads to:

$
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}-\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\phi}}\right)= m \cdot l^2 \cdot \ddot{\phi} + m \cdot l^2 \cdot w^2 \cdot sin(\phi) \cdot cos(\phi) - m\cdot g \cdot l \cdot sin(\phi) = 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$

This can now be adjusted for $\ddot{\phi}$ which results in the following:

$
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       \ddot{\phi}= - w^2 \cdot cos(\phi) \cdot sin(\phi)+\frac{g}{l}\cdot sin(\phi)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$

Is this correct and how do we continue?

Comment: 1. Is $w$ fixed or not? 2. Your kinetic energy doesn't have a $\dot{\phi}$ in it, so it cannot be correct.

Comment: I dont really know, but what would the kinetic energy look like then?

Comment: @whpowell96 you were right I have now edited the question

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\cos$ and $\sin$ using `\cos` and `\sin`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a referential with basis vectors $(\hat i, \hat j,\hat k)$ and making

$$
\cases{
q=r(\hat i \cos(\omega t) + \hat j\sin(\omega t))+q_0 \hat k\\
p = (x(t),y(t),z(t))
}\ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

the lagrangian reads

$$
L(p,\lambda, t) = \frac 12m\|\dot p\|^2-m g p\cdot\hat k+\lambda(\|p-q\|^2-l^2)
$$

Here $\lambda$ is a lagrange multiplier to consider in the variation also the constraint $\|p-q\|=l^2$ and the movement equations are obtained from

$$
\cases{
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot p}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial p}=0\\
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\|p-q\|^2-l^2) = 0\\
 }
$$

or

$$
\cases{2 r \lambda  \cos (\omega  t)-2 \lambda  x(t)+m x''(t)=0\\
2 r\lambda  \sin (\omega  t)-2 \lambda  y(t)+m y''(t)=0\\
g m+2 \lambda q_0-2 \lambda  z(t)+m z''(t)=0\\
r \cos (\omega  t)\left(\omega ^2 x(t)-2 \omega  y'(t)-x''(t)\right)+r \sin(\omega  t) \left(\omega ^2 y(t)+2 \omega x'(t)-y''(t)\right)+(z(t)-q_0) z''(t)+x(t)x''(t)+x'(t)^2+y(t) y''(t)+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2=0
}
$$

Solving for $\{x''(t),y''(y),z''(t),\lambda\}$ we have

$$
\cases{
x''(t)= \frac{(r \cos (\omega  t)-x(t)) \left(r \omega 
   \sin (\omega  t) \left(\omega  y(t)+2 x'(t)\right)+r \omega 
   \cos (\omega  t) \left(\omega  x(t)-2 y'(t)\right)+g q_0-g
   z(t)+x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2\right)}{r^2-2 r x(t) \cos (\omega 
   t)-2 a y(t) \sin (\omega  t)+q_0^2-2 q_0
   z(t)+x(t)^2+y(t)^2+z(t)^2}\\
y''(t)=\frac{(r \sin (\omega t)-y(t)) \left(r \omega  \sin (\omega  t) \left(\omega  y(t)+2
   x'(t)\right)+r \omega  \cos (\omega  t) \left(\omega  x(t)-2
   y'(t)\right)+g q_0-g
   z(t)+x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2\right)}{r^2-2 r x(t) \cos (\omega 
   t)-2 r y(t) \sin (\omega  t)+q_0^2-2 q_0
   z(t)+x(t)^2+y(t)^2+z(t)^2}\\
z''(t)= \frac{-g r^2+r x(t) \cos
   (\omega  t) \left(2 g+\omega ^2 q_0-\omega ^2
   z(t)\right)+r y(t) \sin (\omega  t) \left(2 g+\omega ^2
   q_0-\omega ^2 z(t)\right)+(q_0-z(t)) \left(2 r
   \omega  \sin (\omega  t) x'(t)-2 r \omega  \cos (\omega  t)
   y'(t)+x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2\right)-g x(t)^2-g y(t)^2}{r^2-2 a
   x(t) \cos (\omega  t)-2 r y(t) \sin (\omega  t)+q_0^2-2
   q_0 z(t)+x(t)^2+y(t)^2+z(t)^2}
}
$$

NOTE

The modeling can be done considering polar coordinates as sugested by @mjqxxxx

Making

$$
p = q-l(\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi),\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi),\sin(\theta))\ \ \ \ \ (2) 
$$

and considering now, the Lagrangian

$$
L(p(\theta,\phi), \dot p(\theta,\phi),t) = \frac 12m \|\dot p\|^2-m g p\cdot\hat k
$$

so the resulting movement equations are much more simpler

$$
\cases{
\theta ''(t)= \frac{g \cos (\theta (t))-l \phi
   '(t)^2 \sin (\theta (t)) \cos (\theta (t))+\omega ^2 r \sin
   (\theta (t)) \sin (\omega  t+\phi (t))}{l}\\
\phi ''(t)= 2 \phi
   '(t) \theta '(t) \tan (\theta (t))-\frac{\omega ^2 r \sec
   (\theta (t)) \cos (\omega  t+\phi (t))}{l}
}
$$

Included a MATHEMATICA script with animation

```
parms = {q0 -> 2, l -> 2, r -> 1, m -> 1, g -> 9.81, omega -> Pi/2};
ex = {1, 0, 0};
ey = {0, 1, 0};
ez = {0, 0, 1};
q = r (Cos[omega t] ex + Sin[omega t] ey) + q0 ez;
p = {x[t], y[t], z[t]};
L = 1/2 m D[p, t] . D[p, t] - m g p . ez + lambda ((p - q) . (p - q) - l^2);
mov = D[Grad[L, D[p, t]], t] - Grad[L, p];
equc = D[(p - q) . (p - q), t, t];
equs = Join[mov, {equc}];
sol = Solve[equs == 0, Join[D[p, t, t], {lambda}]][[1]];

equsmov = Thread[D[p, t, t] == (D[p, t, t] /. sol /. parms)];
cinits = {x[0] == r, y[0] == x'[0] == y'[0] == z'[0] == 0, z[0] == q0 - l} /. parms;
tmax = 10 omega /. parms;
solp = NDSolve[Join[equsmov, cinits], p, {t, 0, tmax}];
gr0 = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[p /. solp], {t, 0, tmax}, ViewPoint -> {4, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thin]
Q[t_] := r (Cos[omega t] ex + Sin[omega t] ey) + q0 ez /. parms
X[t_] := Evaluate[x[t] /. solp]
Y[t_] := Evaluate[y[t] /. solp]
Z[t_] := Evaluate[z[t] /. solp]

d = 3;
dt = 0.05; 
ListAnimate[Table[Show[
 Graphics3D[{{Red, Sphere[{X[t][[1]], Y[t][[1]], Z[t][[1]]}, 0.1]},
 {Line[{{0, 0, (q0 /. parms)}, {0, 0, 0}}]},
 {Line[{{0, 0, (q0 /. parms)}, Q[t]}]}, 
 {Line[{Q[t], {X[t][[1]], Y[t][[1]], Z[t][[1]]}}]}}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-d, d}, {-d, d}, {-1/2, d - 1/2}}, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {4, 0, 2}], {t, 0, tmax, dt}]
]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you treating the string like a spring with stiffness $\lambda$ and natural length $d$?  To me the problem reads as if it has a fixed length $\ell$ (but I admit it's not totally clear).

Comment: Thanks for asking. Here $\lambda$ is a lagrange multiplier to attach the constraint $\|p-q\|^2=d^2$

Comment: Ah, okay.  Makes sense.  Though I can't help but think the result would be much simpler in terms of coordinates where the constraint is automatically satisfied.  Say, let $\theta$ be the angle between the string and the vertical, and let $\phi$ be the angle between the string's projection on the $xy$ plane and the (rotating) vector from the center of the disc to the attachment point.  And write the Lagrangian and equations of motion in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: Yes. This can be done also. The cartesian modeling is simpler to conceive, so I choose this way.

Comment: See animation with $r=\frac{1}{2},q_0=1,\omega=\frac{2\pi}{4},g=9.81,l=1,t_{\text{max}}=50$:

[![Animation][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF3Sk.gif

Comment: @gpmath how did you make the animation

Comment: With Mathematica 14.

Comment: Sorry for asking so late but how did you get this term frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\|p-q\|^2-l^2) = 0 I know it comes from the constraining force but why is it the second derivative, why is it not eqaul to zero in the lagragian and why is this the constraining force to beginn with

Comment: $ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\|p-q\|^2-l^2) = 0$ comes from a holonomous constraint. To conveniently handle this, is is necessary that the initial conditions for $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be consistent with the constraint. We choose the second derivative to handle the set $(x'',y'',z'')$ thus eliminating $\lambda$ from the movement equations. The expression obtained to $\lambda$, is the normal force actuating in the constraint.

Comment: Thanks, but why does the holonomous constraint look like this, what is the logic behind p-q^2-l^2

Comment: This constraint establishes that the distance between $p$ and $q$ is $l$. Now $\|p-q\|^2-l^2=0$ is equivalent to $\|p-q\|-l= 0$ but the former is algebraic  friendly.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it so p describes the point mass (while also being the impulse), while q describes the circular motion

Comment: How is the kinetic energy of the system 1/2mg*(m*a)^2 it doesnt seem to make sense

Comment: Where did you get this from? Kinetic energy is $\frac 12 m\|\dot p\|^2$.

Comment: sry for asking now, but where does the 'a' come from in the y and and z formula above

Comment: Please. See $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: Here $a = q = r(\hat i \cos(\omega t) + \hat j\sin(\omega t))+q_0 \hat k$. What do you mean by resonance?